# [React Native]Hide Text Input default Keyboard

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

I have created a customized native keyboard component for my application. Now I want to render that keyboard instead of default one. How can I do this?
I tried

```
<TextInput
              value={clientDetails.city}
              onFocus={() => onFocus('city')}
              onChangeText={value => onStateChange('city', value)}
              placeholderTextColor={colors.placeholderColor}
              placeholder={
                constants.sellerClosingCosts.clientDetailsCityPlaceholder
              }
              onEndEditing={event =>
                onEndEditing('city', event.nativeEvent.text)
              }
              style={styles.textInput}
            />
```

But even when I am not passing any prop value for keyboardType, the default one is opening.

**In short**
 How can I stop keyboard from rendering while editing text input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **showSoftInputOnFocus** false to your TextInput. This disables the device keyboard but the onFocus event still keeps listening and you can call your keyboard there.

```
<TextInput
    showSoftInputOnFocus={false}
    onFocus={() => <CALL_YOUR_KEYBOARD>}
/>
```

Comment: Isn't showSoftInputOnFocus used to show or hide soft keyboard? This will still show default keyboard.

Comment: Are you using iOS or Android?

Comment: @Rohit The second solution is that you can import Keyboard from react-native and call Keyboard.dismiss() on focus event. But this will hide the blinking cursor also.

Comment: I am testing on Android, but it will be used for iOS too.

Comment: Did you try to dismiss it on focus?

Comment: Yes, worked for me. Thanks. Please change the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Rohit Updated.

Comment: showSoftInputOnFocus doesn't work well for me. It sometimes hide the keyboard and sometimes not. Also keyboard.dismiss() cannot be used as it'll loose the focus from textinput.

Comment: What do you mean `<CALL_YOUR_KEYBOARD>` ? How do you open it when `showSoftInputOnFocus` is false ? I tried using the `ref.current.focus()`, it didn't help.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa The author said that he implemented his customized keyboard and wanted to render it instead